# Why do I have one extra 0 in my results when I join two tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

How is it possible this query add one extra 0 in my result?

This would be the correct result:

1. Product: One
2. Coste: 650.00
3. Impresiones: 288154

Instead of that, this is the result...

1. Product: One
2. Coste: 6500.00
3. Impresiones: 2881540

It seems like the result would be multiply by 10.

If I run each query, I have both results correct.  But when I join both tables, I fail.

Could you help me?

thanks!

```html
WITH cost AS (      
  SELECT 
  Ad_name,
  Cost__EUR_ AS Euros 
  FROM 
  `prueba-261316.fb_reach.coste_2019` 
  WHERE producto = 'One'
),

imp AS (
  SELECT
  Ad_name,
  Impressions AS Impresiones
  FROM
  `prueba-261316.fb_reach.impresiones_2019`
  WHERE producto = 'One'
)
SELECT
  cost.Ad_name,
  SUM(Euros) AS Coste,
  SUM(Impresiones) AS Impresiones
FROM      
  cost
LEFT JOIN 
  imp
ON 
  cost.Ad_name =  imp.Ad_name
GROUP BY
  Cost.Ad_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because with your join, you are aggregating results using the `SUM()` operator. So more than likely your join is not producing the singular result you expect, but instead it is producing 10 rows so 650 * 10 = 6500. I'd take a closer look at your join and try to get it under control.

Comment: i would remove "probably" from the answer!

Comment: Yes, but I suppose another possibility is that `Cost.Euros <> rueba-261316.fb_reach.coste_2019.Cost__EUR_`. It is quite difficult to tell without seeing the data.

Comment: This is one example of the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TSNLbUHvtuwxMW40vB30QRd8prEJYf78lMfX3uPqVV0/edit?usp=sharing

I put both tables in one Sheets to share it. 

SUM () in that part is not good for the results? Where could I put it to improve the result?

Thanks so much!

Comment: As @robbpriestley said, this is because of the way you are joining the data. In the example you've given each row in "coste" joins to *ten rows* in "impressiones" when joined on the `Ad_name` column. This means that when you `SUM(Euros)` you are multiplying each cost by 10. It looks like you might be able to avoid this by changing the join to include `Date` as well as `Ad_name` which might give you  one row per ad per day in both tables (although you'd need to do some tests of the data to see if that's a correct assumption).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Nathan!

That was the solution. I only add another conditional and solved!

I made this change in the code, I share just in case someone has the same problem in a future.

```html
WITH cost AS (      
  SELECT 
  Date,
  Ad_name,
  Cost__EUR_ AS Euros 
  FROM 
  `prueba-261316.fb_reach.coste_2019` 
),

imp AS (
  SELECT
  Date,
  Ad_name,
  Impressions AS Impresiones
  FROM
  `prueba-261316.fb_reach.impresiones_2019`
)
SELECT
  cost.Date,
  cost.Ad_name,
  SUM(Euros) AS Coste,
  SUM(Impresiones) AS Impresiones
FROM      
  cost
LEFT JOIN 
  imp
ON 
  cost.Ad_name =  imp.Ad_name
WHERE
  cost.Date = imp.Date
GROUP BY
  Cost.Date,
  Cost.Ad_name
```